# Printing nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
movie_collections_dict = {'Avatar':0, 'Titanic':0, 'StarWar':0}
#which indicates the revenues of the movies
```

and

```
{'avatar': {'adult': 0,
            'child': 0,
            'concession': 0,
            'senior': 0,
            'student': 0},
 'starwar': {'adult': 0,
             'child': 0,
             'concession': 0,
             'senior': 0,
             'student': 0},
 'titanic': {'adult': 0,
             'child': 0,
             'concession': 0,
             'senior': 0,
             'student': 0}}
#which shows that this much seats are booked for a particular ticket type for a movie
```

I want to print the dictionaries in such a way that it will be shown as:

```
         adult  child  student  senior  concession  Revenue
Avatar       0      0        0       0           0        0
Titanic      0      0        0       0           0        0
StarWar      0      0        0       0           0        0
```

**I don't want to use any external modules such as pandas or anything.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you can use `.format()`.

**Code:**

```
movie_collections_dict = {'Avatar': 0, 'Titanic': 0, 'StarWar': 0}
tickets_dict = {'avatar': {'adult': 0, 'child': 0, 'student': 0, 'senior': 0, 'concession': 0},
                'starwar': {'adult': 0, 'child': 0, 'student': 0, 'senior': 0, 'concession': 0},
                'titanic': {'adult': 0, 'child': 0, 'student': 0, 'senior': 0, 'concession': 0}}

print("{:<11}{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}{:<12}{:<12}{:<10}".format(' ', 'adult', 'child', 'student', 'senior', 'concession', 'Revenue'))

for movie_name, revenue in movie_collections_dict.items():
    adult_sales = tickets_dict[movie_name.lower()]['adult']
    child_sales = tickets_dict[movie_name.lower()]['child']
    student_sales = tickets_dict[movie_name.lower()]['student']
    senior_sales = tickets_dict[movie_name.lower()]['senior']
    concession_sales = tickets_dict[movie_name.lower()]['concession']
    print("{:<11}{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}{:<12}{:<12}{:<10}".format(movie_name, adult_sales, child_sales, student_sales, senior_sales, concession_sales, revenue))
```

`{:<10}` means ***left aligned*** and 10 defines minimum width be taken. i.e(**10 characters**) you can change as per your need. you should take padding **atleast greater than** the max character of the word.

**Output:**

```
           adult     child     student   senior      concession  Revenue   
Avatar     0         0         0         0           0           0         
Titanic    0         0         0         0           0           0         
StarWar    0         0         0         0           0           0
```